# Error on return after operating on a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a chunk of code:

```
void split(std::vector<std::string> * v,const char* s,const char* x) {
size_t len = strlen(s);
size_t slen = strlen(x); //slen = Search Length
if(len==0||slen==0)
    return;
v->clear();
char* f = new char[len];
memset(f,0,len);
int * counter =new int;
(*counter)=0;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
    if(isNext((s+(i*sizeof(char*))),x)) {
        f[i]=1;
        counter++;
    }
}
if((*counter)==0) {
    delete [] f;
    delete counter;
    v->clear();
    return;
}
...
```

However when I am debugging it with gdb (on cygwin) or the visual studio debugger I get this error (from the cygwin console)

```
(gdb) step
36              if(len==0||slen==0)
(gdb) step
38              v->clear();
(gdb) step
std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::clear (
    this=0x60003a3e0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:1126
1126          { _M_erase_at_end(this->_M_impl._M_start); }
(gdb)
```

No matter where I compile it I get the same error! When I check the values of all the variables within *gdb* everything is correct (values are exactly what they should be). The vector does work because I intialize it in *main()*, use it and then delete it and reallocate it (all without issue). Am I missing some big thing here? Googling and debugging for hours didn't seem to bring up anything. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the whole point of using things like vectors and strings so that you *don't* have to dig yourself into a memory management hole?

Comment: @chris Maybe, but the function (from requirements from the rest of the program that I can't change) can't return anything (and doing *vector<string> &v* does the same thing) so I'm kinda forced into a corner where that is concerned.

Comment: What the flip is this doing?  `if(isNext((s+(i*sizeof(char*))),x))`?  You're indexing a `const char` array, but you're scaling the index by the size of a `char *`.  That's most assuredly not what you want.

Comment: Also, you say you're operating on a vector, but the only vector operations I see are `v->clear()`.  That hints you're corrupting memory (either through `counter++` or your `isNext()` magic).

Comment: @Joe Z The vector operations are in *main()* and after this piece of provided code (hence the ... at the end of the snippet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot here that can be simplified, but as far as major problems there is this:

```
int * counter =new int;
(*counter)=0;

counter++;
```

The counter++ is incrementing the pointer not the value pointed to.  I don't see any reason why this needs to be a pointer and should probably be avoided as it just adds complexity to this.

What does `isNext` do?  There definitely a lot you can do to simply this and when that's done it will likely reduce problems.

What are you passing to split?  If the vector is uninitialized the call to `->clear()` could cause an access violation.

Comment: Yeah, that should just be `int counter = 0;` and drop the `new`/`delete` entirely.

Comment: isNext takes const char* a and b and checks if a stars with b.

Comment: Agreed. Imma get rid of all this pointer nonsense (even if it takes me a week) because its driving me crazy. Thanks a lot. The counter++ thing fixed my problem.

Comment: Just a few things you might want to consider:  There generally is no reason to pass a pointer to a vector.  Pass that vector as a reference or const reference.  That ensures that what is passed into your function is a valid object.  Pointers should be used with care and as little as possible.  It may be slightly more costly but simply putting char * into a std::string will simplify and reduce problematic situations a lot.  You can get back to char* with the .c_str() member if it's really needed.

Comment: Alright! I'll keep that in mind! Thanks! I'm new-ish to vectors and strings so any tips at all are helpful. :D